# Issue with numba: "cannot unify array" unless I convert scalars to array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to create a very simple function which I want to optimise with numba (or at least verify if numba makes any difference).

I am running numpy 1.19.2 and numba 0.51.2 in an Anaconda installation on Windows.

The function takes 3 numeric inputs: `a, b , c`; the inputs can be scalars or numpy arrays; the output will of course be, respectively, a scalar or a numpy array

The function is fairly simple:

- if a == 0 --> it returns np.nan
- if b == 0 --> it returns a certain number
- otherwise it performs some very simple algebra

### The issue

I have come up with the toy example below (my actual formulas are more complex but I can show what I need to show with this easier example).

- if the inputs are arrays, it works perfectly
- if the inputs are scalar, numba doesn't work (`Cannot unify array(int64, 0d, C) and float64 for '$phi12.0.2'` )
- if the inputs are arrays of size 1 (I make an array out of each scalar) numba works again

### What I tried / similar questions

The closest question I found was  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639526/numba-data-type-error-cannot-unify-array), but the mismatch there was between an int and a float.
Here it is between an array(int64, 0d, C) and a float64. I can convert my inputs to float but the mismatch remains.

Any ideas? I am not sure what the array and the float being compared are, to be honest.

**The one solution I have found is to add a = np.array([a]) at the beginning of the function, but I don't understand why, plus this returns an array of size 1, whereas I'd like a scalar returned in these cases.**

### Toy example

```
@numba.jit
def my_fun(a,b,c):
    
    return np.where(a == 0, np.nan,
                    np.where(b ==0 , 0 , c**2)   )


a = np.arange(0,11)
b = np.arange(3,14)
b[1] = 0
c = np.arange(10,21)

out_array = my_fun(a,b,c)

out_scalar = my_fun(0,0,1)
```

### The exact warning:

```
 NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function my_fun failed at nopython mode lowering due to: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify array(int64, 0d, C) and float64 for '$phi12.0.2', defined at C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\arraymath.py (3276)

File "C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\arraymath.py", line 3276:
    def scalar_where_impl(cond, x, y):
        <source elided>
        """
        scal = x if cond else y
        ^

During: typing of assignment at C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\arraymath.py (3276)

File "C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\np\arraymath.py", line 3276:
    def scalar_where_impl(cond, x, y):
        <source elided>
        """
        scal = x if cond else y
        ^

During: lowering "$36call_method.17 = call $4load_method.1($10compare_op.4, $14load_attr.6, $34call_method.16, func=$4load_method.1, args=[Var($10compare_op.4, refactor numba.py:8), Var($14load_attr.6, refactor numba.py:8), Var($34call_method.16, refactor numba.py:9)], kws=(), vararg=None)" at D:\MY DATA\USERNAME\Python\scratch scripts\refactor numba.py (8)
  @numba.jit
C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:177: NumbaWarning: Function "my_fun" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True.

File "refactor numba.py", line 6:
@numba.jit
def my_fun(a,b,c):
^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\object_mode_passes.py:187: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "refactor numba.py", line 6:
@numba.jit
def my_fun(a,b,c):
^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg,
```

Comment: How about `a = np.array(a)`, the 0d array.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work: `TypingError: array(int32, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence`

Comment: The return type must always be the same dtype. It isn't supported that a function returns a scalar or an array depending on the input. The same holds true if for example a 1D-array or a 2D-array can be returned depending on the input. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-has-a-type-unification-problem

Comment: @max9111 Thanks - very useful! I suspected as much but couldn't find the exact docs. If you write it as an answer Ill be glad to upvote it. Based on this, what do you think of the solution I found and proposed in my answer? Can you think of some ways to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but it's far from elegant, and I am hoping there is a better one.

To recap, I needed a function which:

- works with numba
- works with both scalars and arrays
- returns scalar (not a one-sized array) when the inputs are scalars, and arrays when the inputs are arrays

I have tried the following, and **found option 2 to be the fastest.**

1. my_fun_optimised_1: a function which, without numba, determines whether the inputs are scalar or not, and then calls, accordingly, a sub-function for the scalar case and one for the arrays. Both sub-functions run with numba, but take forever. I guess this is because numba must be re-initialised at each call of the main function.
2. my_fun_optimised_2: similar to the above, except the scalar and array functions, both running with numba, are main functions and not subfunctions. Much much faster.
3. my_fun_non_opt_no_numba : a function which runs without numba.

The results are:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|        Function         | Array: time vs the fastest | Scalar: time vs the fastest |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| optimised numba 1       |                     54,403 |                      42,961 |
| optimised numba 2       |                          1 |                           1 |
| non-optimised, no numba |                      3.409 |                     4.53892 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

What this means is that, on my PC, the non-optimised, no numba code takes 4.5 times longer than "optimsied numba 2" to run on scalars and 3.4 times longer for arrays.
The "optimised numba 1" is not optimsied at all and takes an insane amount of time.

I hope all of this can be of use to other people.

PS I am very well familiar with pitfalls of premature optimisation. I am only doing this because I have a specific case where 60% of the time is spent doing a similar (but not identical) calculation to the one shown here.

The code to time the functions is:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
import timeit
import pandas as pd

def my_fun_optimised_1(a,b,c):

    @numba.jit
    def my_fun_vectorised(a,b,c):
        return np.where(a == 0, np.nan,
                        np.where(b ==0 , 0 , b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3)
                        )
    
    @numba.jit
    def my_fun_scalar(a,b,c):
        if a ==0:
            return np.nan
        elif b == 0:
            return np.nan
        else:
            return b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3
        
    if np.isscalar(a) and np.isscalar(b) and np.isscalar(c):
        return my_fun_scalar(a,b,c)
    else:        
        return my_fun_vectorised(a,b,c)
    

def my_fun_optimised_2(a,b,c):
    if np.isscalar(a) and np.isscalar(b) and np.isscalar(c):
        return fun_2_scalar(a,b,c)
    else:        
        return fun_2_vectorised(a,b,c)
    
@numba.jit
def fun_2_scalar(a,b,c):
    if a ==0:
        return np.nan
    elif b == 0:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3

@numba.jit
def fun_2_vectorised(a,b,c):
    return np.where(a == 0, np.nan,
                    np.where(b ==0 , 0 , b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3)
                    )
    
    
    
def my_fun_non_opt_no_numba(a,b,c):
    # multipl by 1 converts from array to scalar
    return  1 * np.where(a == 0, np.nan,
                    np.where(b ==0 , 0 , b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3) 
                    )

# I couldn't get this to work with Numba
#@numba.jit
def my_fun_non_opt_numba(a,b,c):
    a = np.array([a])
    b = np.array([b])
    c = np.array([c])
    out = np.where(a == 0, np.nan,
                    np.where(b ==0 , 0 , b*a**3 + a*b**3 + a*b*c**3) 
                    )
    return out





r = 4
n = int(100)

a = 3
b = 4
c = 5

x = my_fun_optimised_2(a,b,c)

t_scalar_opt_numba_1 = timeit.Timer("my_fun_optimised_1(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)
t_scalar_opt_numba_2 = timeit.Timer("my_fun_optimised_2(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)
t_scalar_non_opt_no_numba = timeit.Timer("my_fun_non_opt_no_numba(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)

resdf_scalar = pd.DataFrame(index = ['min time'])
resdf_scalar['optimised numba 1'] = [min(t_scalar_opt_numba_1)]
resdf_scalar['optimised numba 2'] = [min(t_scalar_opt_numba_2)]
resdf_scalar['non-optimised, no numba'] = [min(t_scalar_non_opt_no_numba)]
# the docs explain why we should take the min and not the avg
resdf_scalar = resdf_scalar.transpose()
resdf_scalar['diff vs fastest'] = (resdf_scalar / resdf_scalar.min() )



a = np.arange(3,13)
b = np.arange(0,10)
c = np.arange(20,30)

t_array_opt_numba_1 = timeit.Timer("my_fun_optimised_1(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)
t_array_opt_numba_2 = timeit.Timer("my_fun_optimised_2(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)
t_array_non_opt_no_numba = timeit.Timer("my_fun_non_opt_no_numba(a,b,c) " ,  globals = globals() ).repeat(repeat = r, number = n)

resdf_array = pd.DataFrame(index = ['min time'])
resdf_array['optimised numba 1'] = [min(t_array_opt_numba_1)]
resdf_array['optimised numba 2'] = [min(t_array_opt_numba_2)]
resdf_array['non-optimised, no numba'] = [min(t_array_non_opt_no_numba)]
# the docs explain why we should take the min and not the avg
resdf_array = resdf_array.transpose()
resdf_array['diff vs fastest'] = (resdf_array / resdf_array.min() )
```