# Numba typing error occurs when tried to implement an algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, numba, dbscan

I have run into a typing error when I tried implementing a paper using numba, the code is as follow：

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def max_ssdbscan(mst,labels,num_normal_cluster):

    normal_indices=np.where(labels>1)[0]
    cluster_container=[]
    max_reachability=[]
    for i in range(num_normal_cluster):
        cluster_container.append([])
        max_reachability.append(1)
    max_reachability.append(1)
    max_reachability.append(1)
    reachability_matrix=np.ones((len(labels),num_normal_cluster+2))*np.inf

    for i in normal_indices:
        
        visited=set()
        label=labels[i]
        reach=np.zeros(len(labels))
        h=[(5.9,1.0,5)]
        _=h.pop()
        heappush(h,(0.0,0.0,int(i)))
        reached_different=0
        cluster_indices=[1]
        _=cluster_indices.pop()
        cluster_reach=[0.0]
        _=cluster_reach.pop()
        #print(1)
        while(len(visited)<len(labels)):
            distance,pre_dist,current_index=heappop(h)
            max_dist=max(distance,pre_dist)
            visited.add(current_index)
            reach[current_index]=max_dist
            #print(2)
            if((labels[current_index] ==0 or labels[current_index]==label) and reached_different==0):
                #current_index=int(current_index)
                cluster_indices.append(current_index)
                max_reach=max_dist
                cluster_reach.append(pre_dist)
                #print(3)
            elif(reached_different==0 and labels[current_index]!=label):
                reached_different=1
                cluster_reach=np.array(cluster_reach)
                max_i=np.argmax(cluster_reach)
                max_i+=1
                max_i=int(max_i)
                cluster_indices=cluster_indices[0:max_i]
                #print(4)
            else:
                reached_different=1
                
            next_indices=np.where(mst[current_index]>0)[0]
            for next_ind in next_indices:
                if(next_ind not in visited):
                    heappush(h,(mst[current_index,next_ind],max_dist,next_ind))
        #print(5)
        cluster_container[label-2]+=cluster_indices
        cluster_container[label-2]=list(set(cluster_container[label-2]))
        prev_reach=reachability_matrix[:,label].reshape(1,-1)
        reach=reach.reshape(1,-1)
        combined=np.concatenate((prev_reach,reach),axis=0)
        reachability_matrix[:,label]=np.amin(combined,axis=0)
        max_reachability[label]=max(max_reachability[label],max_reach)
    return reachability_matrix,cluster_container,max_reachability
```

in the above function, mst is a 2d distance matrix using numpy array with float data type, labels is a 1-d numpy array and num_normal_cluster is an integer.
The error message I got is as follows:

```
TypingError: Cannot unify list(float64)<iv=None> and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'cluster_reach.3', defined at /home/jiahao/Desktop/cluster_with_outlier/fast_ssdbscan.py (93)

File "fast_ssdbscan.py", line 93:
def max_ssdbscan(mst,labels,num_normal_cluster):
    <source elided>
            reach[current_index]=max_dist
            #print(2)
            ^

During: typing of assignment at /home/jiahao/Desktop/cluster_with_outlier/fast_ssdbscan.py (93)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I am very new to numba. So you may find some parts of my code redundant.

Comment: It is difficult to find the problem without input data. it is better to prepare small example input arrays, not just explaining. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639526/numba-data-type-error-cannot-unify-array

Comment: You need to check for `cluster_reach` dtype conversion in the code (where assignments or ...).